# Every click on a different list item opens the same activity

Tags: android

I want to open further intents when the user clicks on the list but every time I click on a list item the same activity opens up

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class McLarenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
    //this the arraylist and i want to open further activities when a user clicks on a single arraylist an activity about it opens but currently when i click the 1 and 2 list open the same activity opens up.

            final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

            words.add(new Word("2017", "720 S", R.drawable.mclaren2017720s));
            words.add(new Word("2015", "675lt", R.drawable.mclaren2015675lt));
            words.add(new Word("2015", "P1 GTR", R.drawable.mclaren2015p1gtr));
            words.add(new Word("2013", "P1", R.drawable.mclaren2013p1));
            words.add(new Word("1994", "F1", R.drawable.mclaren1994f1));


            WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);


            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long 1) {
                    // the word item clicked
                    Word word = words.get(0);
                    Intent i = new Intent(McLarenActivity.this, mclaren720s.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    //these are the set on clicker i have used but some how they are not working correctly
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    // the word item clicked
                    Word word = words.get(1);
                    Intent i = new Intent(McLarenActivity.this, mclaren675lt.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting item click listener twice. ListView can have only one item click listener. So basically first item click listener is replaced by second and isn't used.

You should set item click listener only once and do different thing depending on `position` (or possibly `id`) value. Something like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Word word = words.get(position); // I don't know why you need `word` variable, it's not used anywhere in your code
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(McLarenActivity.this, mclaren720s.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(McLarenActivity.this, mclaren675lt.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```